# Retina images with Picturefill?

Tags: html, retina-display, picturefill

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to implement retina images with [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/)

This is what I have...and I don't think it's working:

```
<picture>
    <img
    src="img/small.jpg"
    srcet=
    "img/large.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 800px) 900w"
    "img/large.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 800px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 1800w"
    "img/medium.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 640px) 640w"
    "img/medium_2x.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 640px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 1280w"
    "img/medium.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 320px) 320w"
    "img/medium_2x.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 320px) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 640w"
    size="100%"
    alt="">
</picture>
```

The media-queires pull the images that are 2x bigger. Set it to 1.5 for Android devices.